# how to share a portion of a struct/class in a few programs?

Tags: c++, code-reuse

I have a top level program (call it T here) that consists of a few sub-modules, say A,B and C. T uses a large struct/class that contains a lot of configurable parameters, e.g.

```
struct P {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  int d;
  std::string e;
// many more other parameters goes on here
};
```

Each sub-module uses a portion of struct P and communicate that with other sub-modules and T, e.g. A may use something like this:

```
struct Pa {
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

and B may use something like:

```
struct Pb {
  int b;
  int c;
  int d;
};
```

I can copy the whole struct P in each sub-module so that they always can access the data they need but that looks like bad design as data structure are repeated.

Any suggestion for a more neat design?
Thank you.

Comment: why not 3 structs: `usedbyA`, `usedbyB` and `usedbyboth` or something the like. The fact that those parts are needed by your "sub-modules" suggests that it makes sense to encapsulate them in their individual structs

Comment: @tobi303 Currently, I am indeed encapsulating them in their individual structs, but the problem is the 'usedbyboth' part - say if a sub-module needs some fields from 2 other sub-modules as well as the top level program (the top level struct P may have fields that are not shared by any sub modules), then I will have dependencies across all 3 structs.